# Relatório de um objeto por vez com Jaspersoft Studio

Tags: java, html5, orientação-a-objetos, jsf

Tenho um sistema de notas avulso em jsf e primefaces. Eu consegui gerar um relatório conjunto de varias notas ao mesmo tempo, pesquisando através de dois parâmetros de entrada, data inicial e data final. Mas o que eu quero é gerar uma nota sem ter que informar nenhum parâmetro de entrada, o sistemas gera uma lista a partir de uma pesquisa das notas salvas e o usuário selecionar com o mouse a que ele que gerar e então é gerado o pdf.

Esse é o bean que gera o pdf

```
private Date dataInicial;
private Date dataFinal;`

@Inject
private LancamentoTributo lancamennto;
@Inject
private FacesContext facesContext;
@Inject
private HttpServletResponse response;
@Inject
private EntityManager manager;


public void emitir() {

    Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<>();
    parametros.put("data_inicial", this.dataInicial );
    parametros.put("data_final", this.dataFinal );

    ExecutorRelatorio executor = new ExecutorRelatorio("/relatorios/nota_fiscal.jasper", response, parametros,
            "NTFSavemitida.pdf");

    Session session = manager.unwrap(Session.class);
    session.doWork(executor);

    if (executor.isRelatorioGerado()) {
        facesContext.responseComplete();
    } else {
        FacesUtil.addErrorMessage("Nenhuma nota emitida");
    }
}


@NotNull
public Date getDataInicial() {
    return dataInicial;
}


public void setDataInicial(Date dataInicial) {
    this.dataInicial = dataInicial;
}

@NotNull
public Date getDataFinal() {
    return dataFinal;
}


public void setDataFinal(Date dataFinal) {
    this.dataFinal = dataFinal;
}


public LancamentoTributo getLancamennto() {
    return lancamennto;
}


}

 Classe Executor 

private String caminhoRelatorio;
private HttpServletResponse response;
private Map<String, Object>parametros;



private String nomeArquivoSaida;


private boolean relatorioGerado;

public ExecutorRelatorio(String caminhoRelatorio, HttpServletResponse 
 response,Map<String, Object>parametros,
        String nomeArquivoSaida) {

    this.caminhoRelatorio = caminhoRelatorio;
    this.response = response;
    this.parametros = parametros;
    this.nomeArquivoSaida = nomeArquivoSaida;
    this.parametros.put(JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, new Locale("pt","BR"));
  }

@Override
public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {

    try {
        InputStream relatorioStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(this.caminhoRelatorio);

        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(relatorioStream, this.parametros, connection);
        this.relatorioGerado = print.getPages().size() > 0;

        if (this.relatorioGerado) {
            Exporter<ExporterInput, PdfReportConfiguration, PdfExporterConfiguration, 
            OutputStreamExporterOutput> exportador = new JRPdfExporter();
            exportador.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(print));
            exportador.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(response.getOutputStream()));

            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""
            + this.nomeArquivoSaida + "\""); //Download automatico do pdf 
            exportador.exportReport();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new SQLException("Erro ao executar relatorio " + this.caminhoRelatorio, e);
    }

 }

public boolean isRelatorioGerado() {
    return relatorioGerado;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar [JRBeanCollectionDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRBeanCollectionDataSource.html) pasando a lista como parâmetro.

Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
InputStream relatorioStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(this.caminhoRelatorio);
JRBeanCollectionDataSource ds = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(suaLista);
JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(relatorioStream, this.parametros, connection, ds);
this.relatorioGerado = print.getPages().size() > 0;
```